# JSON vs Database for handling large amount of data

Tags: sql, json, database

Hi I'm very new to this area.

I already have a static data represented by JSON files (and sometimes JSON files are too big so that it's divided into files each of 1 MB) .To load any object we locate first the JSON file then load from it the object data.

not sure if this is the right behavior. when u have a large amount of data like this. is it better to use database directly(as I think the query time will be better than loading 1MB json file and getting the object) or there're other aspects to consider when deciding json over database other than the data size ?

Answer (score 2):

Well, it is possible to cut bread with a chainsaw, but a knife is the right tool...

JSON (same with XML) is meant for 1) data exchange 2) small static data and generically defined structures. It is **not designed** to deal with *large amount of data*.

This depends mainly on the question: *What are you doing with the data?* or *How are you reading / filtering / sorting / joining / manipulating ... your data?*

Clear advise: As you have to grab for tricks already (split JSON in fragments for easier handling) go for the *real* database!